# Hyperledger Fabric 1.4.9 new peer syncing with more than 500k Block Height

Tags: synchronization, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, block, peer

I have a question in Hyperledger Fabric network with 2-Orgs and 1 peer each and my block height is 500k and now I want to add another new peer for my Org1.
Now my question is, if I add a new peer and make that new peer as anchor peer for Or1, any issues will be there for transactions during the blocks syncing with the new peer.

I'm using Fabric version 1.4.9

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have followed the below steps and it worked:

- Created a new Peer and added it to the channel for syncing the Blocks.
- Once the sync is completed, verify the Block height in peer logs.
- Add the new Peer to Anchor peers.
- Install chaincode on the new peer.
- Update the connection Profile.
- Invoke a couple of transactions from the client application and verify the transactions.

The above steps resolve my issue which I have logged in my question above.

Answer (score 1):

There will be no such problem but the block syncing is going to take a lot of time. I have also encountered such a scenario in past and it took around 3 days for the peer to sync 450K blocks.